# Relation between surface tension and surfactant concentration

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

Is there a mathematical theory/relation which directly relates surface tension to concentration of surfactant molecules? I know that surface tension decays exponentially as surfactant concentration increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you are looking for is the [Gibbs isotherm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_isotherm) though in practice we usually have to measure it experimentally as the surface excess and chemical potential are hard to calculate from first principles. The chemical potential can be obtained from the concentration at very low surfactant concentrations, but at higher concentrations surfactants form micelles and liquid crystal phases that greatly complicate the calculation.

Comment: Is this applicable for liquid-liquid interfaces? Also, does this take into account a length scale, for instance, I want to know the concentration of molecules at a specific liquid-liquid interface length or interface area?

Comment: It applies to any interface. Note that the surface tension is related to the *surface excess* of the surfactant. To get this we take the concentration at a distance $x$ from the interface and subtract the bulk concentration to get a deviation $\Delta C(x)$, then we integrate this to get the total excess (or deficit) at the interface.